# Black hole Cyg X-1 doesn't seem dense enough

Tags: astronomy

According to wikipedia, here are the Cygnus X-1 vital stats:

```
Mass    14-16[7] M☉
Radius  20–22[8] R☉
```

A radius of 10 R☉ means a volume of 10^3 = 1000 Sols. Divided by 16 M☉ that means that Cyg X-1 is 60 time *less* dense than Sol. So how could it be a black hole?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cygnus X-1 is a binary system, and the radius you cite (taken presumably from [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygnus_X-1)) is the radius of the binary system not the radius of the black hole. The Wikipedia article is highly misleading in this respect.

At least, I think it's the radius of the binary system. 20-22 R☉ is about 0.1 AU which I think is about the suggested spacing between the two stars.

Comment: Thank you! I see it now mentions in the article that the radius of the event horizon is 26 km.

Answer (score 4):

As a side note (rather than addressing the real question [as John did](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/32314/520)), the density of a black hole measured as $\frac{\text{mass}}{\text{volume inside the event horizon}}$ is not fixed and not required to be high. In fact it drops rapidly as the mass grows.
For a Schwarzschild black hole

$$
\begin{array}0
\rho_{BH} 
 & = \frac{M}{V_{EH}} \\
 & = \frac{M}{\frac{4}{3}\pi R_{EH}^3} \\
 & = \frac{3M}{4\pi \left( \frac{2GM}{c^2}\right)^3 } \\
 & = \frac{3 c^6}{32 \pi G^3 M^2}
\end{array}
$$

Of course, for stellar mass black holes this is huge (on order of $10^{16}\text{ g/cm}^3$  for the sun), but it can be quite "reasonable" for the supermassive black holes at the center of large galaxies.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realise how rapidly the density goes down with mass. A bit later I'll sit on that for a 1 million solar mass object, just to see what values of "reasonable" are! Thanks!

Comment: @dotancohen You can read it right off of the formula...you get a factor of $10^{12}$ vis-a-vis a 1 solar mass hole (mass squared, right?), so about $10^4$.

Comment: I seem to have a problem with the units. The initial formula gives `(m/s)^6 / ( (m/s^2)^3 * g^2 )` which reduces to `m^3 / g^2`. What am I doing wrong? According to my finding, density _cannot_ decrease exponentially with mass.

Comment: @dotancohen The units of $G$ are $\text{[length]}^3 \text{[mass]}^{-1} \text{[time]}^2$. That is, it is Newton's gravitational constant *not* the acceleration of gravity near the Earth's surface.  Also, as a matter of vocabulary the final line shows that the density drops *quadratically* with mass not exponentially which would imply a form like $\rho \propto 1/\exp M$

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling that I was using the wrong units for G and you understood exactly why! As for quadratically / exponentially, wouldn't "dropping off quadratically" be `1/x^4` whereas "dropping off exponentially" would be `1/x^2`?

Comment: *wouldn't "dropping off quadratically" be 1/x^4 whereas "dropping off exponentially" would be 1/x^2?* No, and this is important! "Exponentially" is asymptotically stronger than *any* polynomial factor: for some value of $x$, $\exp{kx}$ (which is what exponential means) will always exceed $x^n$ (which is a polynomial relationship). Further quadratic is as-in "the quadratic equation" implying a power of two; don't try to read the "quad" as "four", they come from different roots.

Comment: Thank you, dmckee. I learned Calculus and Differential Expressions in Hebrew, so I did not realise what the "e" in `e^x` really stood for. [Wikipedia explains it.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) Thanks!